# Get JSON value by using variables on the 2nd level of depth

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, cypress

I have a .json file like this:

{
"width": 700,
"height": 1382,
"dataID": {
"id1": "54321",
"id2": "12345"
}
}

I need to get value of id1 or id2 keys dynamically (using a variable). I use Cypress function cy.read() and by using definite strings it works good:

```
cy.readFile(pathToConfigFile).then(($file) => {
const id1value = $file.dataID.id1;
});
```

But how to wrap this expression into variable containing id1?
There is a similar question : [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)
However the solution proposed there refers only to the first level of depth. With square brackets I can get the following values:

```
cy.readFile(pathToConfigFile).then(($file) => {
const customVariable = "dataID";
const id1value = $file[customVariable];
});
```

But in case of it returns id1value = undefined:

```
cy.readFile(pathToConfigFile).then(($file) => {
const customVariable = "dataID";
const id1 = "id1";
const id1value = $file[customVariable][id1];
});
```

Comment: @GrafiCode if `$file[customVariable]` is undefined you cannot access property `id1` on it and this will throw an error.

Comment: I think OP is saying this `const id1value = $file[customVariable][id1];` is `undefined` when it actually should be `54321` code seems to work (ignoring Cypress) https://jsfiddle.net/nqy1r2s9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check the value of the variable after the first check so you know whether you can read the second-level value.

```
cy.readFile(pathToConfigFile).then(($file) => {
  const customVariable = "dataID";
  const id1 = "id1";
  const idValues = $file[customVariable];
  return idValues ? idValues[id1] : undefined;
});
```

Instead of `undefined` you can return some default value if you prefer.

There are also packages which can be used to do this automatically for you, such as [lodash's `_.get()` method](https://lodash.com/docs/#get).